# Why do perfect run scores in the same stage vary so much?

Tags: sky-force-reloaded

I'm sitting with a pen n paper, trying to compute the theoretical maximum score in Stage 1! Why do the base scores vary by up to 3k even on perfect runs?

Till now I have found the wooden crates giving 1000 points/stars/power-ups as the only possible variation. Is there more?

Comment: Are you accounting for bonuses for things like defeating all enemies?

Comment: Yup, by perfect run I meant getting all bonuses in one game

Answer (score 1):

There is some variation in what powerups are dropped from glowing planes and that are found in crates.

If you are full health, then health hearts give you a small amount of points, but these seem to drop randomly with main weapon power ups.

Comment: I was maxed out on main weapon, so the main weapon power ups weren't dropping.. I'm usually full health too since I play with the Limp Berserker.. There wasn't enough noticable variation in the bonuses to cause that much of difference! Anyway it was a long time ago, I've stopped playing after I cleared stage 12! Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

There is a huge points difference in how fast you beat the boss at the end. Don't forget about that!

Comment: Welcome and thanks for contributing. I'm sure the OP will find your input helpful, but it may have been better to post this as a comment, since this isn't really an answer.

Once you have sufficient reputation, you will be able to comment on any post. Until then, [please provide answers that do not require clarification from the OP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).